# What is the history behind the Java-Matlab interface?

Tags: java, matlab

While surfing for a solution to call Matlab from Java, I came to know there's a package **com.mathworks.jmi** that can be imported to toy around with MATLAB from Java.

Who developed this package? Why isn't it officially documented or why is there not any mentioning of this package clearly on Mathwork's site? Why is it still up?

Comment: After a quick google, this appears to answer your question http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google find a couple of good links but the best is

http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/JMI

### Introduction

The code available on this website relies upon the Java MATLAB Interface (JMI). This interface is entirely undocumented and not publicly acknowledged by The Mathworks.

### History

JMI has been included with each version of MATLAB since MATLAB 5.3 (R11) when Java was first integrated into MATLAB.

The oldest public reference to JMI comes from Aguido Horatio Davis of Griffith University. On September 17, 2000 he posted about discovering JMI and testing some of its functionality. In February of 2002 Peter Webb of The Mathworks (makers of MATLAB) published an article entitled "Integrating Java Components into MATLAB" in the News and Notes section of The Mathworks' Newsletters. Additionally, he posted the ImageBrowser code discussed in his article on the website.

The article has since been removed for the website, the page is now a dead link. However, a copy of the article is available on zfhit's blog. The page with the code states that "The file you are trying to view is not in a published state." There are no known existing public mirrors of this example code. The Mathworks has never since posted any information regarding JMI, although a few posts relating to JMI are available on MATLAB Central which is part of The Mathworks website.